# Counting rows in mysql select based on criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to have a SQL select statement (in PHP) that grabs all the data in my table.  Then I'd like to be able to look for certain criteria and give me a count of rows that meet that criteria.

I already can do it by using mysql_num_rows and a separate select per criteria, but that seems inefficient. (i'd have dozens of select statements going)  Is there a way to do it with just one select statement then use PHP to count the various things I want to count?

Edit:
I dont have any relevant code to post since the only code I do have is just an SQL select that does the filtering for me, and then uses mysql_num_rows to count them.  This is what I am trying to avoid doing.

Example Select statement: 
SELECT MDate, Type, MW, Region, Status FROM Scheduler WHERE Status = 'Complete';

In the above example I am looking for Status = Complete but I have several status' that I'd like get counts of individually without having to put a separate Select for each status.

Comment: you'll need to post your code; question's unclear/too broad

Comment: *" Is there a way to do it with just one select statement then use PHP to count the various things I want to count?"* - next to anything's possible. *"I already can do it by using mysql_num_rows"* - why still use an old api that stands to get deleted on your server when updated to php 7?

Comment: Yes it's possible. In fact, it might be possible with one sql statement. But, you haven't provided any info (table schemas, queries, etc.) So, you aren't going to get any useful answers.

Comment: try CASE/COUNT/HAVING and only select the columns you want, rather than "all" and making sure your table's properly indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write some SQL along the lines of ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE `status` IN ("Complete", ...)
GROUP BY `status`
```

Without specifics of your database schema or the code you already have, that's the best answer you'll likely get.